# jQuery Handler error is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery ajax [fileupload](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/). the file is uploaded correctkly but i got error like

```
TypeError: jQuery.handleError is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
```

using jQuery version 1.7.2 and the code is

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload
        (
            {
                url:'<?php echo $currenturl.'&fileupload=enable';?>',
                secureuri:false,
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{'image_desc':image_desc,'gallery_id':curr_time_stamp},
                success: function (data, status)
                {   

                     if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.msg);
                            showprofilepicture();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        )
```

the function showprofilepicture() also not excuted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The jQuery.handleError was removed after the jQuery version in 1.5 you need to write a custom error handler function to solve this like

```
jQuery.extend({
    handleError: function( s, xhr, status, e ) {
        // If a local callback was specified, fire it
        if ( s.error )
            s.error( xhr, status, e );
        // If we have some XML response text (e.g. from an AJAX call) then log it in the console
        else if(xhr.responseText)
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Refer from the [blog](http://www.johnmain.co.uk/blog/2012/06/14/jquery-handleerror-is-not-a-function-issues/). Thanks John Main for your information

Answer (score 0):

```
             if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
            {
                if(data.error != '')
                {
                    alert(data.error);
                }else
                {
                    alert(data.msg);
                    showprofilepicture();
                }
            }
```

should be

```
jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
            url:'<?php echo $currenturl."&fileupload=enable";?>',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{'image_desc':image_desc,'gallery_id':curr_time_stamp},
            success: function (data, status)
            {   

                 if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(data.error != '')
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }else
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                        showprofilepicture();
                    }
            }

        }
    )
```

Comment: i changed this but it is not working i put an alert before the if but the alert is not working