# Jquery AjaxFileupload only works on my localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

Here is my controller:

```
function upload()
{
    //init var
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $file = "";

    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './uploads/product_images/full/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
        'max_size' => '1024',
        'encrypt_name' => true,
        'remove_spaces' => true
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
        $status = 'Error';
        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
    }
    else
    {
        $uploaded = $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        //resize ori image to large image
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/product_images/full/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/product_images/large/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['width'] = 400;
        $config['height'] = 400;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        //resize large image to small image
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/product_images/large/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/product_images/small/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['width'] = 180;
        $config['height'] = 200;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        //resize large image to thumb image
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/product_images/small/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['new_image'] = './uploads/product_images/thumb/'.$uploaded['file_name'];
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['width'] = 80;
        $config['height'] = 80;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();

        $status = "Success";
        $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
        $file = $uploaded['file_name'];
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg, 'file' => $file));
}
```

and my js :

```
$('#upload-btn').on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('.loading').show();

var files = $('#img_list');
var url = 'http://sukukhek.com/admin/products/upload/';

$.ajaxFileUpload
({
    url: url,
    secureuri: false,
    fileElementId: 'file',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (data, status)
    {
        if(data.status == 'Error')
        {
            $('#feedback').html('<div class="alert-box alert-error"><a class="close-box">x</a>'+data.msg+'</div><br>');
            $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#feedback').html('<div class="alert-box alert-success"><a class="close-box">x</a>'+data.msg+'</div><br>');
            $('#title').val('');
            $('#caption').val('');
            refresh_files(data.file);
        }
    }
});

return false;
});

function refresh_files(data)
{
    var p = data.split('.'),
        id = p[0],
        filename = p[0]+'.'+p[1],
        path = 'http://sukukhek.com/uploads/product_images/small/';
    var photo = 'some long html code';
    $('#img_list').append(photo);
}
```

On localhost, that code works perfectly, but when I upload into public_html on my server, file uploaded into upload directory, but the callback function is not working, the loading div still appear, and the new image does not show up.

Addtitional info:

When file upload is empty, it is success send error message on datatype : json, but when file-to-upload is selected, it is uploaded, but the callback function fail.

UPDATE:

On network tab in chrome I got this message on if the file-to-upload is exist.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Upload.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1066</p>

</div>{"status":"Success","msg":"File successfully uploaded","file":"5ea47dfe50826f573b65b63f46190a05.jpg"}
```

Comment: Start by trying to debug it using network tab in your favorite developper tool

Comment: i did, there in no error in network tab, the status is POST 200 OK.

Comment: And is returned result from server the expected one?

Comment: first it showing this handleerror Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'handleError'. but according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107536/jquery-handler-error-is-not-a-function, i have add some code at the bottom at the error is gone. can you help me solve this :(

Comment: May be the platform of the server is different from your local, i mean u may be using windows as local and linux machine as server. this time the / and \ matters.

Comment: yap it return expected result from server only if there is no fileuploaded. if the file is exist, it success uploaded to the upload directory, but the problem is the callback function is does not work

Comment: @SAM so i must change the directory to \ and not / ?

Comment: Set a callback for ajax error and check if it is fired and then error message.

Comment: @AhmadMilzam if your file is uploaded correctly to the server's upload folder, your path is right

Comment: @AhmadMilzam, hey just check your .log files, i think there is a problem with the php code.

Comment: i've add thi code :         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }

Comment: and it alert undefinded, then : syntaxerror, unexpected token <. i cant find that '<' .. this is weird .....

Comment: @SAM hi, can you tell me this alert ajax error means " alert undefinded, then : syntaxerror, unexpected token < " becauce i cant find that '<', my code work perfectly in localhost and my friend's server, this happen only in my server

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()            { 
                   $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

        });
    });
```